# Website too large for Retina display

Tags: javascript, html, css, retina

My website looks very big on Retina display. All fonts and div elements are bigger than what I see in Chrome. Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: Best stack overflow question title ever.

Comment: Give us some code. Did you use px?

Comment: He he greate question name im asuming you mean a bit blury as the size of the images is scaled up ?

Comment: in Retina it is not blurry at all, everything is just scaled up.

Answer (score 0):

If you have problem with the font size, as i understand from your post, i think this example will help you:

```
font-size:16px;
-webkit-font-size:16px;
```

Or try to add this line on body:

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
```

As i experienced, retina display duplicates the fonts size.

Hope this will help you :)